# Asus TF300TL - cannot get videos showing on both tablet and on 8" monitor via HDMI

Tags: video, asus-eee-pad-transformer, hdmi

My issue concerns ability to show video on both tablet and on external HDMI monitor simultaneously.

I just recently bought my very first tablet Asus TF300TL and for its companion a 8" lilliput monitor with HDMI. I had this lovely idea of using this setup for car entertainment for kids in addition to everyday surfing.

Unfortunately I noticed today after brief testing that videos are only showing via HDMI monitor when cable connected, when I stop video and return to Asus desktop the screen is displayed on both 8" ext. Monitor and on tablet.

I've tried to browse around the web, but it seems difficult to find info.

I haven't yet updated to Jelly Bean. Do you think it would bring more options for video output or is this Asus hardware (or firmware) limitation?

I really appreciate if anybody has an idea what could I try, I'm a newbie with tablets and Android in general.